# Tkinter | 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

У меня есть программа которая берет статистику игрока с сайта и показывает ёё в программе.
Но когда я ввожу никнейм то мне выходит ошибка:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)
>   File "C:\Users\MAKSIK\Desktop\Fortnite\test3.py", line 23, in Search
>     Label(root, stats.wins).place(y = 50)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2606, in __init__
>     Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2135, in __init__
>     classes = [(k, v) for k, v in cnf.items() if isinstance(k, type)]
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
> ```

Вот весь код:

```
from fortnite_python import Fortnite
from fortnite_python.domain import Platform
from fortnite_python.domain import Mode
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x600')

ment = StringVar()

entryBox = Entry(root,textvariable=ment)
entryBox.place(x = 280, y = 5)

fortnite = Fortnite('dc4c889e-af19-4e65-8257-8061d3fc453f')

def Search():
    mtext = ment.get()
    player = fortnite.player(mtext, Platform.PSN)
    stats = player.getStats(Mode.DUO)
    Label(root, stats.wins).place(y = 50)

Button(root, text='Search', command=Search).place(x = 410, y = 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Label(root, text=stats.wins).place(y = 50)
```

Если в `stats.wins` строка конечно.